# Windows Server 2019 always changes NetworkCategory for ALL Network Adapters even when only changed for one

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019

I have an Windows Server 2019 with two network cards. One with a public ip and one with a private ip. Now windows automatically set both adapters to use the "public profile".
What I am trying to do is set only ONE network adapter from Public to Private.

Like this:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-NetConnectionProfile


Name             : Netzwerk
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet 2
InterfaceIndex   : 2
NetworkCategory  : Public                <----- Both are set to public
IPv4Connectivity : Internet
IPv6Connectivity : NoTraffic

Name             : Netzwerk
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet
InterfaceIndex   : 16
NetworkCategory  : Public                <----- Both are set to public
IPv4Connectivity : Internet
IPv6Connectivity : NoTraffic



PS C:\Users\Administrator> Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceIndex 2 -NetworkCategory private
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-NetConnectionProfile


Name             : Netzwerk
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet 2
InterfaceIndex   : 2
NetworkCategory  : Private                <----- Now BOTH are set to private
IPv4Connectivity : Internet
IPv6Connectivity : NoTraffic

Name             : Netzwerk
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet
InterfaceIndex   : 16
NetworkCategory  : Private                <----- Now BOTH are set to private
IPv4Connectivity : Internet
IPv6Connectivity : NoTraffic



PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

So: When changing the network type of one adapter BOTH are actually changed.

Any ideas on this?

Thanks!

Comment: They are both on the same network: `Netzwerk` so would have the same network category.